# Doing a query in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, database-connection

I am editing an index.php file in the themes folder and I just need to run a query but I cant seem to run a query...here is what i tried

i tried to include the config files

```
<?php require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php'); ?> 
<?php print DB_NAME;exit; ?>
```

that printed nothing

then i tried to do the mysql_query command

```
mysql_connect($server, $username, $password)
$users = mysql_query("select * ....");
print_r($users); exit;
```

nothing in either one....i know there has got to be an easier way to do a query in wordpress...any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use mysql directly (as a mysql connection already exists). Instead use the wpdb 'abstraction' - see the wordpress documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class